# HTML Agility pack is changing </p> tag to <p> on invalid markup

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack, xmlconvert

With an input of:

```
<head><title>Title</title></head>
<font face="Verdana" size="2">
<p>

<b>Bold sentence.</b>
<br><br>Sentence after two  breaks.<br><br>Sentence after another two  breaks. <b><i>bold and italicized sentence.</i></b> sentence. <br><br>final sentence after two more breaks.

</font></p>

<form><center><div style='padding-left: 16px; padding-right: 16px;'><a class='button' href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='javascript:window.close()'><img src='/GBUIAssets/Web20/img/frame/buttonshade.png' alt='buttonShade' /><span class='roundLeft'><span class='roundRight'>Fermer</span></span></a></div></center></form></font>
```

im removing the head, font and form. And the output I get is:

```
<p>

<b>Bold sentence.</b>
<br><br>Sentence after two  breaks.<br><br>Sentence after another two  breaks. <b><i>bold and italicized sentence.</i></b> sentence. <br><br>final sentence after two more breaks.

<p>
```

This is problematic because I'm trying to convert it to xml after and this will throw an error. Why is it "fixing" a part of my code that's already valid? Any ideas what could be causing it? I can supply more code if needed, but I just want to make sure first that there's no obvious step I'm missing.

EDIT: for the sake of full context, I'm stripping the html for its body content. Catch is, this HTML is HIDEOUS. Really really ill formatted. I'm loading it into xml to throw the specific errors that are wrong with the html doc and spitting that into an error report for each file that failed to strip

Comment: your markup is invalid. you are closing the p tag outside of the font tag. however you declare the opening p tag within the font tag.

Comment: yeah this markup was written by someone else and it's plagued with errors. So you think it's this nesting fault that's causing the issue in htmlagilitypack? @MikeCorcoran

Comment: yes, HAP is trying to 'fix' the html soup. in this case it isn't fixing it exactly in the way you want. you may need to pre-process the file with certain heuristics to work around it.

Comment: It might be sufficient to replace "</font></p>" with "</p></font>" prior to processing it with HAP.

Comment: @MikeCorcoran Is there any really intelligent HTML fixer that exists out there? Currently I'm loading the HTML into an XML doc and then reading the error, fixing the HTML and recompiling...

Comment: Why are you loading HTML into an XML doc?  HTML is *not* a subset of XML.

Comment: @Amy for the sake of full context, I'm stripping the html for its body content. Catch is, this HTML is HIDEOUS. Really really ill formatted. I'm loading it into xml to throw the specific errors that are wrong with the html doc and spitting that into an error report for each file that failed to strip

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out ... There is no official way how invalid HTML should be converted to valid one - so HAP pick *a way* that probably work in enough cases. You may want to try different parser or even grab DOM from liver browser (using Selenium or PhantomJS) if you find one that matches *your* expectations of the  conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Marpup is invalid. Try putting the font tag in side the P tag and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Update your markup to:

```
<head>
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<font face="Verdana" size="2">
<p>

<b>Bold sentence.</b>
<br/><br/>Sentence after two  breaks.<br/><br/>Sentence after another two  breaks. <b><i>bold and italicized sentence.</i></b> sentence. <br/><br/>final sentence after two more breaks.

</p>

<form>
<center>
<div style='padding-left: 16px; padding-right: 16px;'>
<a class='button' href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='javascript:window.close()'>
<img src='/GBUIAssets/Web20/img/frame/buttonshade.png' alt='buttonShade' />
<span class='roundLeft'><span class='roundRight'>Fermer</span></span>
</a>
</div>
</center>
</form>
</font>
```

If possible, I'd recommend moving the `<font>` declaration into an external stylesheet, e.g.

```
body { font-face: Verdana; }
```